# Don't quite understand JComboBox itemListeners

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

So if i have a combo box "box", and the array it is set to has the values "hello" and "world",
how do i detct which one is selected?

Answer (score 1):

```
box.getSelectedItem();
```

This returns an object that is selected. Here is the javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Answer (score 1):

call getItem() on the ItemEvent that is passed to your ItemListener

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getSelectedItem()` to get the selected one.

```
String name[] = {"One","Two","Three","Four"};
JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(name);
combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie){
       String str = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
       System.out.println("Selected Item is: " + str);
   }
});
```